# Google Analytics 4 Fire custom event not working

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm a web developer who's new to Google Analytics 4 and I can't seem to get custom event working.

**What I want to achieve**

- I want detect when users click specific buttons on my web-application.

**What I already did**

- Created a Google Analytics account
- Created a new Property in Google Analytics
- Add the custom Google Analytics code (including my Measurement ID) to my `head` in my application
- Created a custom event named `get_started`. Note: in the list of events this event doesn't show up, but when I click the *Create event* button it does show up in that list.
- Included code in my application to fire an event with the `gtag` function, which looks as follows: `window.gtag("event", "get_started", { param1: 'tester' });`

**What is currently working**

- In my Google Analytics dashboard it shows when a user visited my website.
- In my network tab I can see that the `get_started` event gets fired and the event includes the correct Measurement ID.

I'm not sure what I'm missing here. Hopefully somebody can help me out.